# Is there any way to add a new layer in caffe that keeps weight which type is unsigned int?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, quantization

I want to add a new binary convolution layer that implement  the [xor-net](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/xnor.pdf) with binary weight and the problem is that I don't know how to save the weight as type of unsigned int. Is there any way to change the blobs_ data type of a layer in caffe?

Answer (score 0):

`Bolb` data type is defined in [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L10-L22). You can see that it has two pointers

> ```
> repeated float data = 5 [packed = true];
> repeated double double_data = 8 [packed = true];
> ```

This means caffe can only work with either `float` or `double` Blob data. If you want to have a `uint8` Blob you'll have to modify `caffe.proto` and re-build caffe.

Comment: Thank you very much. And can I set both unsigned int weights and float bias?